# Parse server resends email verification every time user updates their details

Tags: email, parse-platform, parse-server

I have email verification/password-reset with parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter that works. However, now, whenever a saveInBackground() function is called on a puffer, an email-verification email is sent out again with the user's emailVerified field in the database reset to false. Here is the code I have in my index.js pertaining to email:

```
// Enable email verification
  verifyUserEmails: true,
  emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration: 3 * 60 * 60, // in seconds (2 hours = 7200 seconds)

  // set preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail to false to allow user to login without verifying their email
  // set preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail to true to prevent user from login if their email is not verified
  preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail: true,
```

Comment: which version of parse-server are you using?

Comment: parse server version: 2.2.24